# Session expired when page redirect Asp.net c#

Tags: c#

I had set session in sql state and assign value like  `Session.Add("fbemail", "true");` then I am redirect the page like   `Response.Redirect("user.aspx");` but in my next page I am not getting my session value it's automatically expired.

Comment: what session mode do you have? cookies enabled?

Comment: i had set following in my web config for session 

<sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="server=50.56.96.130;database=Guestbook;uid=sa;pwd=spadmin@81" timeout="15" />

Comment: did you prepare your database for the use of sessionState? (ie: use of `Aspnet_regsql.exe`or `InstallSqlState.sql`)? could you add the eventHandler Code in which you set session var and redirect?

Comment: yes in my databas i am able to seel all table and sp related to session

Comment: please add the complete eventHandler code. Perhaps you destroy appDomain by mistake...

Comment: i am not able to understand what you are saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57261/discussion-between-pilgerstorfer-franz-and-samir).

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect ends the current thread to redirect to the next page. It's an easy fix, Response.Redirect("google.com") comes default with an invisible true boolean set next to it. Just do this **Response.Redirect("your url", false);** and it will finish the current thread.